# Setting Pid cgroup limit

Tags: security, kubernetes, containers, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I am getting the following twistlock vulnerability:

(CIS_Docker_CE_v1.1.0 - 5.28) Use PIDs cgroup limit

How can set the cgroup pid limit using the kubernetes deployment yaml file?

I know docker run has the flag for setting pid limit, but we are not using docker run.

Can anyone please advice?

Comment: are you running latest docker engine? may be it is resolved in a more recent version.

Comment: Just checked it. Didnt seem to resolve the issue. This is a container vulnerability

Comment: ok. do yo have a link to the CVE? I'd like to look into it as well. We have bunch of workloads on GKE.

Comment: Hi, section 5.28 here: https://paper.bobylive.com/Security/CIS/CIS_Docker_Community_Edition_Benchmark_v1_1_0.pdf    .......... Thank you

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem ?

Comment: Nope :(... cant trace any solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes 1.14, they have added a feature that allows for the configuration of a kubelet to limit the number of PIDs a given pod can consume. If that machine supports 32,768 PIDs and 100 pods, one can give each pod a budget of 300 PIDs to prevent total exhaustion of PIDs.

The parameter (`PodPidsLimit`) is part of the kubelet configuration:  [kubelet-configuration](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/apis/config#KubeletConfiguration).

```
// The maximum number of processes per pod.  If -1, the kubelet defaults to the node allocatable pid capacity.
PodPidsLimit [int64](https://godoc.org/builtin#int64)
```

To see current configuration and if the parameter is available in your current version:  [generate-configuration-file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/#generate-the-configuration-file).

Take a look: [pid-limit-kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/15/process-id-limiting-for-stability-improvements-in-kubernetes-1.14/#:~:text=Thus%2C%20in%20Kubernetes%201.14%2C%20we,prevent%20total%20exhaustion%20of%20PIDs.), [pid-limit-pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272911/how-to-set-pid-limit-in-kubernetes-pod).

Comment: Set pids limit at pod level #57973 ( https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/57973 ), Feature Gates ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/ )